# Using Charts. Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I am very new to Charts so please bear with me!
I have installed the 'Charts' CocoaPod (ByDaniel Cohen Gindi and Philipp Jahoda) and so far i have the following:

[image]

And have the following code:

```
class AnalysisViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

var testName : [String]!

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    barChartView.descriptionText = ""
    barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: nil)
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: testName, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData
    chartData.setDrawValues(false)


    chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 16/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1), UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 166/255, blue: 134/255, alpha: 1),UIColor(red: 135/255, green: 66/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1), UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 11/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)]
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
}


func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {
    print("\(entry.value) in \(months[entry.xIndex])")

    //need to set chartData.setDrawValues(true)
}

func setLabels() {
    label1.text = testName[0]
    label2.text = testName[1]
    label3.text = testName[2]
    label4.text = testName[3]

    label1.textColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 16/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)
    label2.textColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 166/255, blue: 134/255, alpha: 1)
    label3.textColor = UIColor(red: 135/255, green: 66/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    label4.textColor = UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 11/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
 barChartView.delegate = self

 testName = ["Food", "Entertainment", "Misc", "Clothes"]

let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0]


    setChart(testName, values: unitsSold)
    setLabels()
}
```

I was wondering about the following:

1. How can i remove the x-axis labels?
2. How can i remove the "Key" (coloured squares) as i am aiming to produce a table underneath the chart but using labels for this purpose.
3. When you select a value on the chart display that values numerical value. I tried to set the ChartDataEntry's setDraw value however this did not work "      ChartDataEntry.setDrawValues(true)".
4. Can you set limits per value rather than the whole  chart? Similar to what you see on Box Plots.
5. How do i remove the y-axis on the right hand side?

Apologies if this is not the correct place to ask these questions. I am new and have been struggling to find the answers else where.

Thanks,

Jess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new, please walk through ChartsDemo to get yourself familiar with it.

*How can i remove the x-axis labels?* Use `xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false`

*How can i remove the "Key" (coloured squares)?* Use `chartView.legend.enabled = false`

*When you select a value on the chart display that values numerical value?* Use `ChartMarker`

*Can you set limits per value rather than the whole chart? Similar to what you see on Box Plots.* Don't know what are you talking about

How do i remove the y-axis on the right hand side? Use `chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false`